# RDP Not Working For New Users (The connection was denied because the user is not authorized for remote login)

Tags: windows, permissions, rdp

New users are not allowed to RDP even though they have the same permissions as existing users. The only work around is to go to System Properties > Remote > Remote Desktop> Select Users and add the users there. This is not very scale-able as we have a couple hundred computers and the clients use rdp often enough where this would be problematic.

I searched the internet and most of the solutions are things like going to Security Settings > Local Properties > User Rights Assignment > Allow Log on through remote desktop and making sure the right groups are there, making sure the user is added to the Remote Desktop Users group, and checking the service to make sure it is local. I have tried these to no avail.

I even made a user and added them to the administrator group (so the user has the same permissions as me) and I would still receive the error.

If anyone has any information to help it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> New users are not allowed to RDP even though they have the same
>   permissions as existing users.

What do you mean by that? What permissions are you referring to?

User rights and permissions are two different things. User rights determine what a user can do (Shutdown the system or log on through Remote Desktop Services). Permissions determine what a user can access (Access the HR folder on the file server).

Users require both user rights and permissions to logon via RDP. User rights =  **Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services**. Permissions (on the RDP protocol) =  **Allow** `Guest Access` and **Allow** `User Access`. The easiest way to grant both of these is to add the users to the local Remote Desktop Users group on the computers you want them to be able to log onto via RDP.

[image]

[image]

> The only work around is to go to System Properties > Remote > Remote
>   Desktop> Select Users and add the users there.

Yes. That's what you need to do.

> This is not very scale-able as we have a couple hundred computers and
>   the clients use rdp often enough where this would be problematic.

This isn't difficult to solve. Use Gropu Policy Preferences in a Group Policy Object to add the Domain Users security group to the local Remote Desktop Users group on the computers you want them to be able to log onto via RDP.

Comment: When a recently created user attempts to remote desktop they get the error mentioned originally. 
Ive used the copy function of a long time existing user to create an account, and same error, but the original user I copied it from has rdp access. 
When a make a new user and manually assign the permissions, I get the sameerror.

Comment: When you said Use Group Policy Preferences in a Group Policy Object to add the Domain Users security group to the local Remote Desktop Users group on the computers you want them to be able to log onto via RDP. Sorry, I am new to AD, how would I go about doing this.

Comment: Copying an existing user doesn't make the new user a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group unless the new user is a member of a security group that is a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group.

Comment: https://www.vkernel.ro/blog/add-domain-users-to-local-groups-using-group-policy-preferences

Comment: Thank you so much, hopefully it works. I really appreciate it!